# Implementing Frequent(every 10 sec) API Polling in Android MVVM App with WorkManager for Learning Purposes

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, alarmmanager, android-workmanager, foreground-service

**Question:**

I'm working on a simple Android MVVM app for learning purposes, where I need to fetch data from a REST API every 10 seconds, even when the app is killed. I understand that WorkManager has a default minimum repeated interval of 15 minutes, which doesn't meet my requirement. Here's a simplified version of my code structure:

**ApiInterface:**

```kotlin
interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("search?country=India")
    suspend fun getUniversities() : Response<University>
}
```

**ApiUtilities:**

```kotlin
object ApiUtilities {
    val BASE_URL = "http://universities.hipolabs.com/"

    fun getInstance() : Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```kotlin
class UniversityRepository(private val apiInterface: ApiInterface) {

    private val universityLiveData = MutableLiveData<University>()

    val university : LiveData<University>
        get() = universityLiveData

    suspend fun getUniversities() {
        val result = apiInterface.getUniversities()
        if(result.body() != null) {
            universityLiveData.postValue(result.body())
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```kotlin
class UniversityViewModel(private val universityRepository: UniversityRepository): ViewModel() {

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            universityRepository.getUniversities()
        }
    }

    val university: LiveData<University>
        get() = universityRepository.university
}
```

Given that I'm a beginner and this is for learning purposes, what's the best approach to implement frequent API polling every 10 seconds, even when the app is killed? I've looked into WorkManager, but the minimum interval seems to be 15 minutes, which doesn't meet my requirement. Any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

With Android 13 and up, there are now some new permissions that make it harder to poll with the app killed.

I recently did something similar with the Foreground service. This creates a notification in the app center letting the user know the app is still running a process in the background.

But it allows you to execute continuous code on a background thread but only with the explicit users permission and visibility.

here are the google docs on foreground service. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-service